# Почему defaultValue не меняется визуально?

Tags: reactjs

Странная ситуация, есть input, для вывода из state Redux дал атрибут defaultValue. Через инспектор вижу что количество меняется( при клике ) но визуально цифра остается одна и та же. Если ставлю вместо defaultValue просто value то тогда работает, но React ругается

Comment: А код где? *[5 символов]*

Comment: При изменении отображается value, defaultValue это как placeholder если я верно помню.